# How to display product details when selecting a product using Realtime Database?

Tags: html, angular, firebase-realtime-database

The code that I have at the moment is the same one that I use to show all the products of some category.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductosService } from '../../services/productos.service';
import { ProductoDescripcion } from '../../interfaces/producto-descripcion.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comprar',
  templateUrl: './comprar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comprar.component.css']
})
export class ComprarComponent implements OnInit {
  cargando = true;
  producto: ProductoDescripcion [] = [];
  id:string;


  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
               public ProductoService:ProductosService) { 
               }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
    .subscribe(parametros => {
      //console.log(parametros['id'])

      this.ProductoService.getProducto(parametros['id']) 
      .subscribe( (producto: ProductoDescripcion [] )=> {

         this.id = parametros ['id']
         this.producto = producto;
         console.log(producto)
         this.cargando = false;
      });
    });
  }

}
```

[The problem is that when I click on a product, it returns the details of all those in the category.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQSIj.png)

[My database is the following.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkeD3.png)

my products.service.ts, I have the option to load products and below the option to get the details of my products.

````
export class ProductosService {

  cargando = true;
  productos: Producto[] = [];
  productosFiltrar:Producto[]=[];

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {

    this.cargarProductos();
   
  }  
  
private cargarProductos() {
 return new Promise<void>( (resolve, reject)=>{
  this.http.get<Producto[]>('https://angular-html-2b54e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/productos_idx.json')
  .subscribe( (resp: Producto[]) => {

    console.log(resp);
    this.productos = resp;
    this.cargando = false;
    resolve();

  });

 });
}

getProducto(id:string) {
return this.http.get<ProductoDescripcion[]>(`https://angular-html-2b54e-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/productos/${id}.json`)
}```
````

Comment: How does your service look like?

Comment: @BojanKogoj I have already placed it